# How to resolve null reference exception in Httpcontext in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I need to sign out the Azure login and need to redirect it to another URL. For that, I have used the logout method but facing an exception in HttpContext. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue? Here is my code. When I click the logout button the below code will be executed.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task Logout()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").AddEncryptedProvider();
    Configuration = builder.Build();

    string url = string.Empty;

    url = Configuration["Azure:LogOutURL"] + Configuration["Azure:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];    

    HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: You can dive deeper into the exception information by looking at the 'InnerException' object. That should tell you what the 'real' problem is.

Comment: There is no inner exception only this message I am getting in the catch block

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext throwing a null reference means that your configuration file is not setup correctly so the configuration lookups are returning null thus URL == null

Comment: I have already added the configuration url which I mentioned here in the app settings file I am not getting an issue in the configuration issue is httpcontext throwing nulll even after adding the Httpcontextaccessor service in startup file. Could you please give me a solution to resolve this issue

Comment: Have you dependency inject Httpcontextaccessor into your service, then call HttpContext like this: _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url);

Comment: yes I have added the httpcontextaccessor service and ensured as you mentioned above but still it's not working